# Firebase: What is the purpose of projectId and apiKey for cloud messaging 20.1.1

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

According to new release of Firebase Cloud Messaging, to create a firebase app using FirebaseOptions, you must provide `projectId` and `apiKey`.

---

#### [Firebase messaging release note](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#messaging_v20-1-1) says:

> Apps that use the Firebase auto-initialization process and the Gradle plugin to convert google-services.json into resources are unaffected. However, apps that create their own FirebaseOptions instances must provide a valid API key, Firebase project ID, and application ID.

---

#### To reproduce:

When creating a `FirebaseApp`, the code that *fails* with `firebase-messaging:20.1.1` or higher, but used to work on lower versions:

```
// Fails with `FIS_ERROR` on firebase-messaging:20.1.1 or higher
// Works with 20.1.0 or lower

val builder = FirebaseOptions.Builder()
    .setGcmSenderId(fcmSenderId)
    .setApplicationId(appId)

FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context, builder.build(), "SecondApp")
```

Two `ApiKey` and `ProjectId` is required in the new changes. So if I pass this:

```
// Works and messages will be received and sent, but the values are wrong

val builder = FirebaseOptions.Builder()
    .setGcmSenderId(fcmSenderId)
    .setApplicationId(appId)
    .setApiKey("noapikey")
    .setProjectId("noprojectid")

FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context, builder.build(), "SecondApp")
```

#### What works with even invalid values

- `onNewToken` will give the token
- `onMessageReceived` will pass received messages
- Upstream messages will be sent

In general, the library will work as expected.

My question is, when I pass dummy strings, it still works. What is the use of these two keys for firebase cloud messaging?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code that isn't working the way you expect. We should be able to duplicate the issue on our own by following the instructions in your post.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for the respond. An edit has been made to the post and some snippets added.

Comment: And what is the code that uses Firebase APIs that continues to work even though you initialize with invalid values?  Please be specific about what you're observing.

Comment: An edit has been made. The functionalities that work are listed.